# Is it okay to seek freelance work outside of full-time employment?

Tags: freelance

Is it okay to seek freelance work outside of full-time employment?

I am mainly looking for something more challenging and satisfying in regards to work so I can use my head a bit more.  I don't want to leave my current full-time position since I've only been there a year and aside from losing matching 401k contributions, equity, etc.  I feel it'd be distraction on my resume.

EDIT #1:
The contact says that I may not work for a competitor, supplier, or vendor of the company.  There is an additional statement which says that it must not interfere with my performance, that is a given to me.  If I take on additional work outside my normal work and my performance suffers as a result, that is a no brainer that I shouldn't be taking on additional work.

So, if I interpret that in black and white, if I work for a financial company, then I cannot work for a competing financial company, but if I work for a farm, that is perfectly fine unless the farm is a vendor the company.

Comment: We can't answer this question as it depends on the contract you signed with your current employer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to address this is to send an Email to your manager or HR asking if you can do after-hours freelance and explain what you will do (to show it won't compete or interfere with your current job).  Spin it by saying this will help you pick up more skills and experience that will help you do your current job better.  If they respond saying they approve, make sure you keep/save that email for CYA purposes.

Comment: The reason I'm considering outside work is that my current work isn't stimulating.  I'm aware of marketing it, but that also carries significant risk of basically saying that you're not satisfied with work.  I have adapted myself to work so that I can do the best possible whilst also getting some enjoyment out of it, but it is like expecting a Formula 1 race, but instead you're at a pinewood derby race.  Even after removing the engine and floor, I can still go faster than the others.